# Send file on save event kendo gird

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-upload

I have the following scenario: I'm using a kendo CRUD grid (MVC) and for each row a user should be able to upload a template. My question is if is possible to send the uploaded templates when the user press Save.

Comment: What means _upload a template_? Do you mean upload a file that results that is a template but for KendoUI it doesn't matter if it is a template or a photo?

Comment: Yes I mean a file, doesn't matter which type it is.

Comment: The grid is set for in-line or pop-up mode? Also, where is supposed the file to be located?

Comment: Now the grid is set for in-line mode. An user can upload a file which is stored after that in a table in database